# Performing aggregation on cube throws unexpected error

Tags: python, python-3.x, olap, cubes

I want to create a cube from csv data file and to perform and aggregation on it, the code is below:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from cubes.tutorial.sql import create_table_from_csv
from cubes import Workspace, Cell, browser

import data
if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///data.sqlite')
    create_table_from_csv(engine,
                             "../data/data.csv",
                             table_name="irbd_balance",
                             fields=[
                                ("category", "string"),
                                ("category_label", "string"),
                                 ("subcategory", "string"),
                                  ("subcategory_label", "string"),
                                  ("line_item", "string"),
                                 ("year", "integer"),
                                 ("amount", "integer")],
                            create_id=True
                      )
    print("done. file data.sqlite created")
    workspace = Workspace()
    workspace.register_default_store("sql", url="sqlite:///data.sqlite")
    workspace.import_model("../model.json")


    cube = workspace.cube("irbd_balance")

    browser = workspace.browser("irbd_balance")

    cell = Cell(cube)
    result = browser.aggregate(cell, drilldown=["year"])
    for record in result.drilldown:
        print(record)
```

The tutorial and the library are available here:

https://pythonhosted.org/cubes/tutorial.html

The error stack is :

```
result = browser.aggregate(cell, drilldown=["year"])
  File "C:\Users\path\venv\lib\site-packages\cubes\browser.py", line 145, in aggregate
    result = self.provide_aggregate(cell,
  File "C:\path\venv\lib\site-packages\cubes\sql\browser.py", line 400, in provide_aggregate
    (statement, labels) = self.aggregation_statement(cell,
  File "C:\path\venv\lib\site-packages\cubes\sql\browser.py", line 532, in aggregation_statement
    raise ArgumentError("List of aggregates should not be empty")
cubes.errors.ArgumentError: List of aggregates should not be empty
```

It seems the tutorial is containing some typos. Any idea how to fix this?
Else is there any other better olap cubes library for Python that has great docs?